# NDK - include error

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need your help because it drives me crazy. What cause my error?

The error is

```
"jni/algorithm.cpp:4:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory  #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
                                 ^ compilation terminated. make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/algorithm/algorithm.o] Error 1"
```

My algorithm.cpp is:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_hematoma_MainActivity_fce(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong matimage)
          {
              Mat *jni_image  = (Mat*) matimage;

              return (jlong)jni_image;

          }
}
```

My Android.mk is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include /home/nemesis/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := algorithm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := algorithm.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDE := /home/nemesis/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDE += /home/nemesis/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The error occurs when ndk try to build .so

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDE := /home/nemesis/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2
```

should be

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /home/nemesis/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include
```

ie, it is plural and should point to the location from which the following is a relative path:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

Comment: Oh great, such a mistake, thank you, you are the best :) but it didnt completly fixed my problem, now there are these errors "In file included from jni/algorithm.cpp:4:0:
/home/nemesis/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:56:21: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
 #include <algorithm>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/algorithm/algorithm.o] Error 1"

Comment: You will have to provide the path for that as well, and/or correct it to point to something that actually exists.

Comment: I fixed it, I hate eclipse ndk :D the problem was that I had before in Android.mk LOCAL_MODULE := algorithm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := algorithm.cpp             BUT there is only one file .cpp so It should be grammatically correct LOCAL_SRC_FILE and not FILES... oh I am so angry and happy at same time. Big thank to Chris

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by add `LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl` to "Android.mk"

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include C:/.../OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := Testappcv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Testappcv.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And added "Application.mk" file to jni folder

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Comment: APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions

was the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried to change in Project properties C/C++ Build -> Build command from ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build to ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd and it solved all my include libs errors.  weird

Comment: Say what?  That is a windows script, while your directories indicate you are on linux!  Perhaps this "fixed" your issue by not trying to build at all?   Your real solution should probably be to set the include path in your Android.mk

Comment: Thank you Chris but what do you mean? I said that it is weird because I am in linux not windows. What would be my solution? include what? NDK? do you think that ndk didnt build at all?

Comment: You can tell if it built by looking for .so files in the project directory.  Normally, to solve your error I would suggest you add an include path pointing to where opencv keeps its files to your Android.mk

Comment: I tried to add it as you can see above  LOCAL_C_INCLUDE := /home/nemesis/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp   but it didnt work :/

Comment: That was the right idea, but not quite right in the details - see my answer